# Why do I get a 'valueError' despite explicitly returning the expected number of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is merge sort tweaked to count inversions. My code throws an odd error 
(I'm implementing algos to learn python 3.x).

> In line 11,
>
> in merge_sort  first_sorted_half, x = merge_sort(arr[:half])
>   [Previous line repeated 12 more times]   ValueError: not enough values
>   to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Even though I explicitly return two values? I'm new to python 3 so I'd like to understand exactly what's going on here, I can't seem to find a similar issue anywhere. A link to python docs for more on this would also be appreciated!

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    half = int(len(arr)/2)
    first_sorted_half, x = merge_sort(arr[:half])
    second_sorted_half, y = merge_sort(arr[half:])
    merged_halves, z = merge(first_sorted_half, second_sorted_half)

    return merged_halves, x + y + z


def merge(first_half, second_half):
    n = len(first_half) + len(second_half)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    split_inversions = 0
    ans = []
    for k in range(n):

        if i >= len(first_half):
            ans.append(second_half[j])
            j += 1
            continue
        if j >= len(second_half):
            ans.append(first_half[i])
            i += 1
            continue

        if first_half[i] > second_half[j]:
            ans.append(second_half[j])
            j += 1
            split_inversions += len(first_half) - i
        elif first_half[i] < second_half[j]:
            ans.append(first_half[i])
            i += 1

    return ans, split_inversions


numbers = [3,2,1,4,5,6,8,10,9]
print(merge_sort(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting says that your program executed that recursive call 12 times, and at the end it couldn't *unpack* the result.

What that means is, python expects you to return two values from `merge_sort`, because you unpack the result into `first_sorted_half` and `x`. However, when you return only `arr` from the condition `len(arr) <=1`, there is no value to unpack, only there exists the array.

So how you fix that is returning a value for the base case, like `return arr, len(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst ilke444 is right - a bit more clarification is needed. To start: returning data variables is what you need but I do not know much about the    len(arr) <=1    , and I am quite new to stackflow, I do not know this feature of Python 3. I specialize in Pygame/ standard packages.

First thing - arr in this "Code Snippet" (If it is) is not defined; and/or will need to be defined. Len stands for length as you know - and uses a quote (' ') to use it.
Like so:

```
len('arr')
```

would print:

```
3
```

because there are 3 Characters in this set. You are obviously new to python 3 as you said because the syntax is slightly different.

As this probably only solves the first bit - with this info I will leave you with 1 thing more.
Call to print requires a quote (' '),
Lists have [ ] Brackets instead of (),
Dictionaries have {} brackets and variables now require definition either by variable definition or function unless put in quote marks.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: And, btw your probably getting a syntax error in a really weird way.

Comment: not really, arr is just the variable name for my list. the only change I had to make was return arr, 0 for my base case (len(arr) <=1).